# Javascript alternative for lookbehind in regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regular expression with negative lookbehinds, since it's not supported in Firefox and Internet Explorer, need an alternative to the lookbehinds. Can someone help me out here with a modified expression?
Here is the expression:

```
((?=^.{1,254}$)(^(((?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\.)+(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-))\.?$)|(^((?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-))$))
```

I tried modifying the expression like this, but still it doesn't work as expected:

```
((?=^.{1,254}$)(^(((?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}"([^"-]?)"\.)+(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}"([^"-]?)")\.?$)|(^((?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}"([^"-]?)")$))
```

Can someone help me out here?

Following are the test cases that need to work withoutlookbehinds in the expression:

1. *.abc - should not work
2. - - should not work
3. pg.ing-ad - should work
4. [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) - should work
5. *.de; - should not work
6. a - should work
7. *.d-e - should not work
8. www.abc def.com - should not work

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: What are you trying to match? Please give some example strings that should match and some that shouldn't.

Comment: A simple '-' shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: Strings like abc.com, pg.ing-ad should be allowed

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62660027/edit) and add test cases.

Comment: How about: `^(?=.{1,254}$)[a-zA-Z0-9](?:(?:-?[a-zA-Z0-9]){0,62}\.?)+$`

Comment: @Toto I've added the test cases.

Comment: @Toto All the cases are passing except case like abc. shouldn't be allowed, but it's being allowed. Can we restrict that also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This passes all your test cases:

```
^(?=.{1,254}$)[a-zA-Z0-9](?:(?:[-.]?[a-zA-Z0-9]){0,62})+$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Jk6yBS/3)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It almost works, but one case is still failing.

Comment: If I enter abc. it is getting passed

Comment: When I do a backspace, the browser crashes with this regex. Any idea?

Comment: @SashiKiran:Sorry, I don't see. You should ask a new question with part of code that shows this behaviour.